# CI/CD w/ SFDX: Where to store the jwtkeyfile in my repo?

Tags: salesforcedx, git, docker, cicd

I was following some notes online and managed to setup a CI/CD pipeline in bitbucket using Docker and SFDX. I used the following command in the .yaml file:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile keys/server.key --username $SFDC_QA_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias testPipelines --instanceurl $SFDC_QA_URL
```

Everything is working however I can't figure out a good way to store the private key. Currently "jwtkeyfile" is a required value and I don't see a place on bitbucket to store that file. I was hoping that they would have something similar to the "repository variables", maybe "repository files" but they don't.

I don't want to store the private key in the repo itself even though the repo is private.

Is there a way to encrypt the key value that is in the repo and have sfdx decrypt it using a "repository variable"? I am struggling to find information related to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common strategy is to encrypt the JWT keyfile and commit the encrypted version to source control (perhaps under an `assets` directory). Then, you store the passphrase in a CI variable so that your built script can decrypt it.

I have some [example files](https://github.com/davidmreed/circleci-sfdx-examples) that do this with CircleCI, but it works the same way with most CI providers. You just do

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k "$KEY" -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -d
```

where `$KEY` is your CI variable holding the passphrase for your encrypted JWT key `server.key.enc`. This happens right before you call `sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant`.

I like to also use a cleanup job to delete the plaintext key as soon as it's not needed so I don't have to worry about accidentally persisting it as a job artifact.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing as well. One thing that is unclear to me is what happens at the end of the transaction if I don't delete the outputted decrypted server.key. I thought it was not preserved anywhere?

Comment: @Arthlete It probably wouldn't be. I delete it as part of my script just so that I don't have to understand or worry about any changing behavior in preserving build artifacts.

Comment: Thank you, I will modify my yaml file as well to reflect on that thought.

Answer (score 2):

1. Store the JWTKey in a Repository variable.
2. Run a bash command to create a file and store JWTKey from the Environment variable to that file. (Something like `printf $JWT_KEY > server.key`)
3. Now, run

   `sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile server.key --username $SFDC_QA_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias testPipelines --instanceurl $SFDC_QA_URL`